# How to synchronize an NTFS partition with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, partitioning, ntfs

I have an NTFS partition, on this partition I have all documents, images, music, etc, but I can't synchronize these folders with Ubuntu One.

Comment: How do you mount the partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can symlink the folders to the Ubuntu One folder, but only if you are using Ubuntu to do the syncing. If you are syncing on Windows it will not work.

An example of how you can do this is:

```
ln -s /dev/sda6/users/username/Documents ~/UbuntuOne/Documents
```

**NB:**
You will have to do this from a terminal, as it is currently not possibly to link to a specific location from within Nautilus (there is a script for it but is broken in the most recent Nautilus versions).

**UPDATE:**
For some reason, they've changed this (it changed cause it worked for me before), as Chipaca pointed out. However I will leave my answer here as a sign post (for reasons).

*You cannot synch the folders apparently. **Use dropbox until U1 allows you to use symlinks.***

Comment: Ubuntu One does not synchronize nor follow symlinks.

Comment: @Chipaca: That's odd (I know you're one of the main developers), and I've heard you say it before (though in relation to windows), but I've done it on my system before and had it synch the folders, so I'm only going based on what happened for me.

Comment: My experience (and I'm not confused with dropbox) is that it follows symlinks.

Comment: It does not. I'm not sure what you're seeing, but it most definitely does not follow symlinks. They're explicitly ignored.

Comment: @Chipaca: Then something is wrong with Ubuntu One in a major way - because I've used it to synch several things by symlinking O.o...

Comment: @Chipaca: Okay now... you are right (at least now) - but I don't get it because the files that were previously synching (they were, I'm not lying or kidding) are no longer synching. When did you make that change (and why?). Is it because of Windows?

Comment: The version in Ubuntu has never supported them. We have explicitly ignored symlinks since 2009 (which is why we get away with the "Shared with me" symlink inside your Ubuntu One folder). The support for symlinks that we did have was intended to sync the symlink itself, not follow it, and was never implemented beyond the protocol level.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the NTFS-folder to a folder of your home directory and then choose in Ubuntu One to sync.

```
mkdir /home/user/ntfsFolder
sudo mount --bind /media/ntfsPartition/folderToSync /home/user/ntfsFolder
```

To make the bind permanent, add this line to your fstab:

```
/media/ntfsPartition/folderToSync /home/user/ntfsFolder none bind 0 0
```